# Get At Least X Characters Before Keyword PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm making a small search system using php and mysql.

I have this:

```
preg_match('#(.{75}' . $s . '.{75})#s', $b, $match);
if (isset($match[1])) {
   return preg_replace('#(.+?)' . $s . '(.+)#s', '$1<span><b>' . $s . '</b>     </span>$2', $match[1]);
} else {
    return 'Error';
}
```

This does a good job of getting the first appearance of the keyword(s) and getting 75 characters before and after it. The only problem is that if there is less than 75 characters, it will not go through. I am pretty new to regex and I actually got help with the above code and it's not fully mine.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do regex on your own, you should try to find the answer yourself. In this case, it's not that difficult.

Comment: Also consider using `preg_replace`'s fifth parameter `&$count`, instead of running regular expressions twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to match any characters from `n` number up to 75, if that is your case all you have to do is: `{10,75}` where `10` is the `n` number(lower) limit in your regex.

```
'#(.{10,75}' . $s . '.{10,75})#s'
```